# missing spree gem, can t install it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, spree

I have cloned a git repository of a project, that is using spree, and I want to run it on localhost.

But as I said in an article, I can not install spree gem:

```
$ rake gems:install
Missing the Spree 0.10.2 gem. Please `gem install -v=0.10.2 spree`, update your SPREE_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the Rails version you do have installed, or comment out SPREE_GEM_VERSION to use the latest version installed.

$ gem install -v=0.10.2 spree
Successfully installed spree-0.10.2
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for spree-0.10.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for spree-0.10.2...

$ script/server
Missing the Spree 0.10.2 gem. Please `gem install -v=0.10.2 spree`, update your SPREE_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the Rails version you do have installed, or comment out SPREE_GEM_VERSION to use the latest version installed.

$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.5)
actionpack (2.3.5)
activemerchant (1.5.1)
activemodel (3.2.8)
activerecord (3.2.8, 2.3.5)
activerecord-tableless (0.1.0)
activeresource (2.3.5)
activesupport (3.2.8, 2.3.5)
arel (3.0.2)
authlogic (3.1.3)
authlogic-oid (1.0.4)
builder (3.0.3)
bundler (1.2.1)
chronic (0.2.3)
faker (0.3.1)
highline (1.5.1)
hoe (3.1.0)
i18n (0.6.1)
less (1.2.20)
multi_json (1.3.6)
mutter (0.5.3)
paperclip (2.3.1.1)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.1.0, 1.0.1)
rails (2.3.5)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.0)
rvm (1.11.3.5)
searchlogic (2.3.5)
spree (0.10.2)
state_machine (0.8.0)
stringex (1.0.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.33)
whenever (0.3.7)
will_paginate (2.3.11)
```

I tried to google this problem, and found branches like this:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/spree-user/Fhn_PgFQ6i8

But the solution did not work for me.

Here is my system:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- ruby 1.8.7 (2012-06-29 patchlevel 370) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: You should try using bundler http://gembundler.com/

Answer (score 0):

You're using an ancient version of Spree there. We would recommend using the latest. Please follow the [Getting Started Guide](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/getting_started.html).